# REGEX filename Shellscript check

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to write a bashscript check using regex to distinguish between the following files. I am trying to select DRLIC_INFO_20170912.out in the if statement and not DRLIC_INFO_20170912_TEMP.out. 20170912 will be a daily timestamp.

Input filenames:

```
DRLIC_INFO_2017-09-12.out
DRLIC_INFO_2017-09-12_TEMP.out
```

Current check:

```
SEARCH_DRLIC_INFO='DRLIC_INFO'

if [[ $filename == *$SEARCH_DRLIC_INFO* ]]
```

Comment: Try `if [[ $filename == *$SEARCH_DRLIC_INFO\.* ]]`

Comment: Hi I added an update to make my question more clear. Trying to select the first file and not the second.

Comment: @Defcon, please have a look to my answer and let me know if this helps you,

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
filename1="DRLIC_INFO_20170912_TEMP.out"
regex="DRLIC_INFO_[[:digit:]]+_TEMP.out"
if [[ $filename1 =~ $regex ]]; then echo "File named "$filename1 " found."; else echo "File name " $filename1 " not found."; fi
```

Or in case you want to be specific about date that string should have 8 digits in it you could change above regex variable to following too.

```
regex="DRLIC_INFO_[[:digit:]]{8}_TEMP.out
```

**EDIT:** If you want to use SEARCH_DRLIC_INFO variables as shown by you, you could try following then and let me know then.

```
SEARCH_DRLIC_INFO="DRLIC_INFO"
filename1=$SEARCH_DRLIC_INFO"_20170912_TEMP.out"
regex="DRLIC_INFO_[[:digit:]]{8}_TEMP.out"
if [[ $filename1 =~ $regex ]]; then echo "File named "$filename1 " found."; else echo "File name " $filename1 " not found."; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a regular expression here at all. If you know the exact format of your file, then you can make a glob pattern which matches it. By specifying the part at the end, you prevent the file including `_TEMP` from matching:

```
timestamp=20170912
for file in DRLIC_INFO_"$timestamp".out; do
    echo "$file" # for debugging
    # :
done
```

The loop only demonstrates that the file that you want matches - if you want, you can replace the body with `:` (do nothing, return success). After the loop, `$file` contains your file name.

Alternatively, you can use an array:

```
files=( DRLIC_INFO_"$timestamp".out )
echo "${files[0]}"
```

In this case the 0th element is your file.